Intercepted Route On Same Level (.) Not Working Next JS
I have been following the documentation of Nextjs
My folder structure is this

When I am on folder1 route and when I redirect to folder2 route using Link It should render Intercepted route of folder 2 But It is rendering the normal route of folder2.
Even I tried restarting the dev server and also removing the .next folder as well.
Any Solution?
